# Sympy Can't differentiate wrt the variable

Tags: sympy

I am trying to evaluate a function (second derivative of another one) but Sympy seems to have a difficulty to do that... ?

```
from sympy import *
from sympy import Symbol

# Symbols
theta = Symbol('theta')
phi = Symbol('phi')
phi0 = Symbol('phi0')
H0 = Symbol('H0')
# Constants
a = 0.05 
t = 100*1e-9
b = 0.05**2/(8*pi*1e-7)
c = 0.001/(4*pi*1e-7)
phi0 = 60*pi/180 
H0 = -0.03/(4*pi*1e-7)
def m(theta,phi):
    return Matrix([[sin(theta)*cos(phi), sin(theta)*cos(phi), cos(phi)]])
def h(phi0):
    return Matrix([[cos(phi0), sin(phi0), 0]])
def k(theta,phi,phi0):
    return m(theta,phi).dot(h(phi0))
def F(theta,phi,phi0,H0): 
    return -(t*a*H0)*k(theta,phi,phi0)+b*t*(cos(theta)**2)+c*t*(sin(2*theta)**2)+t*sin(theta)**4*sin(2*phi)**2
def F_theta(theta,phi,phi0,H0):
    return simplify(diff(F(theta,phi,phi0,H0),theta))
def F_thetatheta(theta,phi,phi0,H0):
    return simplify(diff(F_theta(theta,phi,phi0,H0),theta))

print F_thetatheta(theta,phi,phi0,H0), F_thetatheta(pi/2,phi,phi0,H0)
```

As seen below, the general function is evaluated but when I try to replace theta by pi/2 or another value, it does not work.

```
(4.0e-7*pi*sin(theta)**4*cos(2*phi)**2 - 4.0e-7*pi*sin(theta)**4 + 0.00125*sin(theta)**2 - 0.0001875*sqrt(3)*sin(theta)*cos(phi) - 0.0001875*sin(theta)*cos(phi) + 1.2e-6*pi*cos(2*phi)**2*cos(theta)**4 - 1.2e-6*pi*cos(2*phi)**2*cos(theta)**2 - 1.2e-6*pi*cos(theta)**4 + 1.2e-6*pi*cos(theta)**2 + 0.004*cos(2*theta)**2 - 0.002625)/pi
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "Test.py", line 46, in <module>
print F_thetatheta(theta,phi,phi0,H0), F_thetatheta(pi/2,phi,phi0,H0)
File "Test.py", line 29, in F_thetatheta
return simplify(diff(F_theta(theta,phi,phi0,H0),theta))
File "Test.py", line 27, in F_theta
return simplify(diff(F(theta,phi,phi0,H0),theta))
File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/sympy/core/function.py", line 1418, in diff
return Derivative(f, *symbols, **kwargs)
File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/sympy/core/function.py", line 852, in __new__
Can\'t differentiate wrt the variable: %s, %s''' % (v, count)))
ValueError: 
Can't differentiate wrt the variable: pi/2, 1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error means you can not differentiate with respect to a number, pi/2. Ie, you derive with respect to a variable (x, y...), not a number.

In an expression with several variables, you can substitute one of them (or more) by its value (or another expression) by using `subs`:

```
F_thetatheta(theta,phi,phi0,H0).subs(theta, pi/2)
```

Then, to evaluate it to the desired accuracy you can use `evalf`. Compare the two results:

```
F_thetatheta(theta,phi,phi0,H0).evalf(50, subs={theta:pi/2, phi:0})
F_thetatheta(theta,phi,phi0,H0).subs({theta: pi/2, phi:0})
```

You should probably have a look at the [sympy documentation](http://docs.sympy.org/dev/modules/evalf.html) or follow the [tutorial](http://docs.sympy.org/dev/tutorial.html). The documentation is very good, and you can even try the examples in the browser and evaluate code.

Comment: Yes, sorry I understand now the error. I should read the tutorial on sympy, I will definitely need it! But your suggestion didn't work actually. This worked instead: `F_thetatheta(theta,phi,phi0,H0).subs(theta,pi/2)`

Comment: @user1816760 Ops, you're absolutely right, I didn't realize phi was still in the final expression, and in that case you need to substitute theta as you did. If you were evaluating both theta and phi at the same time this would work: `F_thetatheta(theta,phi,phi0,H0).evalf(subs={theta:pi/2, phi:0})`. At any rate, you'll end up needing `evalf` to get a numeric value instead of the exact one (I'll fix my answer).