# Cannot differentiate wrt a complicated variable in Sympy

Tags: python, physics, sympy

(I understand the title makes this sound like a duplicate question to [Sympy Can't differentiate wrt the variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13351288/sympy-cant-differentiate-wrt-the-variable), but I'm fairly certain it is quite different. I apologize in advance if I am mistaken)

I'm trying to solve the Double Pendulum using Hamiltonian Mechanics, but Sympy is having trouble taking one of the derivatives. The code is below, but it's much easier to read the [iPython Notebook over at nbviewer.ipython.org](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/github/pixatlazaki/iPython_Notebooks/blob/master/Double_Pendulum.ipynb)

```
from __future__ import division
from sympy import *
init_session()
r_1,r_2,l_1,l_2, m_1, m_2, rdot_1, rdot_2,g = symbols("r_1 r_2 l_1 l_2 m_1 m_2 \dot{r_1} \dot{r_2} g")
phi_1, phi_2 = symbols("phi_1 phi_2", cls=Function)
phi_1 = phi_1(t)
phi_2 = phi_2(t)

r_1 = Matrix([l_1 * sin(phi_1), -l_1 * cos(phi_1)])
rdot_1 = r_1.diff(t)
r_2 = Matrix([r_1[0] + l_2 * sin(phi_2), r_1[1] -l_2 * cos(phi_2)])
rdot_2 = r_2.diff(t)

T = (1/2) * m_1 * rdot_1.T * rdot_1 + (1/2) * m_2 * rdot_2.T * rdot_2
T = T[0]

U = -g * ((m_1 * r_1[1]) + (m_2 * r_2[1]))

L = symbols("\mathcal{L}")
L = T - U

H = symbols("\mathcal{H}")
H = T + U

p_1, p_2 = symbols("p_1 p_2")
p_1 = L.diff(phi_1.diff(t))
p_2 = L.diff(phi_2.diff(t))

eq1_1 = p_1.diff(t) + H.diff(phi_1)
eq1_2 = p_2.diff(t) + H.diff(phi_2)
eq2_1 = phi_1.diff(t) - H.diff(p_1)
```

The last line yields the following error:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-96-83bfafadd08f> in <module>()
----> 1 eq2_1 = phi_1.diff(t) - H.diff(p_1)
      2 eq2_2 = phi_2.diff(t) - H.diff(p_2)

/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/sympy/core/expr.pyc in diff(self, *symbols, **assumptions)
   2773         new_symbols = list(map(sympify, symbols))  # e.g. x, 2, y, z
   2774         assumptions.setdefault("evaluate", True)
-> 2775         return Derivative(self, *new_symbols, **assumptions)
   2776 
   2777     ###########################################################################

/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/sympy/core/function.pyc in __new__(cls, expr, *variables, **assumptions)
   1027                 from sympy.utilities.misc import filldedent
   1028                 raise ValueError(filldedent('''
-> 1029                 Can\'t differentiate wrt the variable: %s, %s''' % (v, count)))
   1030 
   1031             if all_zero and not count == 0:
ValueError: 
Can't differentiate wrt the variable:
1.0*l_1*(l_1*m_1*Derivative(phi_1(t), t) +
l_1*m_2*Derivative(phi_1(t), t) + l_2*m_2*cos(phi_1(t) -
phi_2(t))*Derivative(phi_2(t), t)), 1
```

Is the expression too complicated? Or am I misunderstanding how to use diff()?

Comment: This came up in a rather unrelated Google search, but keep in mind that the behavior of Sympy changed in 1.2, if you're getting errors like "there are no variable in the expression" this in a third party library it might be a good idea to try something like [Sympy 1.0 instead](https://bitbucket.org/fenics-project/fiat/issues/27/sympy-12-breaks-diff-of-expression-without).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's essentially the same problem. The second argument to `diff` (or the only argument if called as a method) should be a single Symbol, not an expression. In this case, your differentiation "variable" is an entire expression, which doesn't even make sense mathematically.

Comment: When I differentiated `L` wrt `phi_1.diff(t)`, isn't that also differentiating a function wrt an expression? If I am still in error, how would one perform the operation expressed in Hamilton's equations? Thank you so much for the help, by the way.

Comment: It is allowed to differentiate with respect to a single function or a single derivative, because this makes sense (you just replace that function or derivative with a dummy symbol everywhere and differentiate with respect to that). See http://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/core.html#sympy.core.function.Derivative.

Answer (score 1):

Did you perhaps inadvertently overwrite p_1?

```
p_1, p_2 = symbols("p_1 p_2")
p_1 = L.diff(phi_1.diff(t))
```

You created a symbol but then destroyed it by creating a Python variable with the same name, so when you try to differentiate wrt p_1 you are (as Aaron pointed out) differentiating wrt an expression, not a symbol that you created.