# I am trying to write some code about simple nonlinear regression

Tags: python, sympy, non-linear-regression

I am trying to run a simple program about nonlinear regression in pycharm, but failed.
The reason is:

```
ValueError: Can't calculate derivative wrt x**2.
```

and here is my code.

```py
import sympy as sy

object_c = 2.13
x = sy.symbols('x')
a = x ** 2
b = sy.ln(a)
c = sy.sqrt(b)
x_val = 2

da_dx = sy.diff(a, x)
db_da = sy.diff(b, a)
dc_db = sy.diff(c, b)
dc_dx = sy.diff(c, x)

fc = sy.lambdify((b,), dc_db)
c_val = fc(x_val)
dc = c_val - object_c

while dc > 0.001:
    db = dc / dc_db
    da = db / db_da
    dx = da / da_dx

    x_val = x_val - dx
    c_val = fc(x_val)
    dc = c_val - object_c

print('done!')
print('final x is %f' % x_val)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cannot differentiate wrt a complicated variable in Sympy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25188084/cannot-differentiate-wrt-a-complicated-variable-in-sympy)

Comment: Thanks for your help. Now I know where the problem is!!!